# If M is connected and f is continuous, prove that the graph of f is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The graph of $f: M \to \mathbb R$ is a set $\{(x,y) \in M \times\mathbb R : y = f(x)\}$
Since $M \times\mathbb R$ is a Cartesian product of two metric spaces it has a natural metric.

a) If $M$ is connected and $f$ is continuous, prove that the graph of $f$ is connected.

b) If $M$ is path-connected and $f$ is continuous, show that the graph is path-connected.

Comment: Disgusting. They vote to close a good question and don't even leave a single comment. Don't get discouraged by this kind of people that roam this site. Ask questions, they will always be answered.

Comment: @user144349 No.  This site is not a magical place where you ask a question and someone else does your thinking for you.  Anyway: I highly recommend you reading the pages upon pages of discussion on meta regarding this issue--you will find that "those people who roam the site" are not a small contingent.

Comment: @anorton I have read all of that. I am also surveying the closed questions and can tell that this is indeed a magical place where you post questions and get answers. It is very very rare the closed questions that doesn't have an answer. You and those that like to close questions for not showing work need to meditate for a few minutes if the *good intention of trying to make students work (through an online website)* is really producing any good effect. So far (120+ out of 9000+) closed questions the closed questions that deserved it are minimal with respect to those that didn't deserve it ...

Comment: And the ratio of closed questions for not showing work and with complete answers is almost 100% of all closed for this reason.

Comment: (a) Assume that $U_1\cup U_2$  are disjoint, non-empty opens sets of $\text{Graph}(f)$ and $V_1, V_2$ their projection to the $y$-axis. Then $f^{-1}(V_1)$ and $f^{-1}(V_2)$ are disjoint, non-empty opens that cover $M$. This is impossible by definition of $M$ being connected.

Comment: (b) Let $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ be points of the graph of $f$. Since $M$ is path-connected there is a continuous $g:[0,1]\to M$ such that $g(0)=a$ and $g(1)=b$. Then $G:[0,1]\to\text{Graph}(f)$ given by $t\mapsto (g(t),f(g(t)))$ is a continuous path that connects $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$.

Answer (score 5):

(a) The graph is the image of $M$ by a continuous function:
$$F:M\longrightarrow M\times\Bbb R$$
$$F(x)=(x,f(x))$$
(b) $\cdots$

Answer (score 2):

You can the path-connecteness only. It's the same thing. So take $(a,f(a)),(b,f(b))\in G$ where $G$ is the graph of $f$. Then because $M$ is connected there is a continuous curve $\gamma$ such that $\gamma (0)=a$ and $\gamma (1)=b$. Then the curve $g=(\gamma ,fo\gamma)$ is continuous and takes $(a,f(a))\to (b,f(b))$.